# List object versions in a S3 bucket via signed URI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, uri, versioning, signed

In our project we're storing objects in a S3 bucket with versioning enabled. There's no logic on the server besides creating a signed URI for the client to use. We'd like to keep it this way as we want the client to do all the processing.

To the problem. We're successfully able to generate signed URIs for a GET and PUT object for the whole objects, but we're unable to generate a URI for listing all available versions.

This is an example of a GET-url on a object in one of our buckets which works (the 99/2 are folders in the bucket):
https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/99/2?AWSAccessKeyId=ourkey&Signature=signature&Expires=1410784420

According to the docs ([GET versions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETVersion.html)) we're supposed to append ?versions and the different versions. We've tried the following:
https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/99/2?AWSAccessKeyId=ourkey&Signature=signature&Expires=1410784420&versions

This then results in the browser complaining that the signature is wrong, it's missing "?versions". If I read [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheCanonicalizedResourceElement) I interpret it as it shouldn't be included in the signature unless we append a value to it as well, which we aren't. The problem is then that it doesn't matter if I then add it to the signature creation as it still fails with the error "There is no such thing as the ?versions sub-resource for a key".

Is there someone who has successfully created a signed uri for object to list it's versions? We'd really love to get some pointers on what we're doing wrong!
I'd also like to point out that we're not using the built in URI-generator as we couldn't get it to fit our needs.

Answer (score 0):

Listing object versions is an operation performed "against" the bucket, not against the object... so your path is always going to be `/`, no matter what keys you want to list.

You specify the key prefix in the query string as `prefix=...`.

The string to sign would then begin with `/bucketname/?versions&prefix=...`.

You sort all of the query string parameters lexically, *except* for the subresource (`versions`, in this case), which goes first.  If more than one subresource, you also sort them lexically among themselves, but they still go first.  Everything is separated by `&` in the string to sign.

Significant caveat: the list api may not be appropriate to hand over to the client, since you can end up returning the wrong things... "prefix" is just that -- a prefix. If it doesn't match exactly, it can match on substrings, which might not be what you want. You may also need to use `delimiter` and `max-keys` and be prepared to handle the pagination through truncated listings that will become necessary when a large number of results is returned.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETVersion.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html